# Visio 2010: Change basic Template

Tags: microsoft-visio

I created a few 'bubble diagrams' using the Brainstorm Diagram option.  I learned that only one input connection can be made to my bubble.  I can have multiple input connectors in the Basic Diagram.  Is there a way I can change my existing Brainstorm Diagrams into Basic Diagrams without recreating all of them?

Thanks tons for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no method to directly change Brainstorm Diagrams into Basic Diagrams. When you open the diagram in Visio, it will recognize the stencils or template you used for current page automatically.

If you want to use another template (Basic Diagram), create a new page or template and add new shapes manually for it.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you can only have one input on a bubble? I've just created a brainstorming diagram and had no problem creating multiple inputs.